# D3js: Enlarge section of sunburst on hover

Tags: d3.js, hierarchy, partition, sunburst-diagram

I use a d3.hierarchy together with d3.partition to setup a sunburst chart. I set the value and the size with hierarchy.count() (which counts the children and set the count as value for each node) in order to equally size the sunburst chart on each level.

[image: parcel]

Is it possible to enlarge only one section of the sunburst chart on hover (without changing its position)? If I use e.g. transform scale(1.5) also the position is shifted towards the outer bounds of the sunburst chart.

Edit://

I used this code to generate the sunburst arcs:

```
const arc = d3.arc<d3.HierarchyRectangularNode<any>>()
            .startAngle(d => d.x0)
            .endAngle(d => d.x1)
            .padAngle(d => Math.min((d.x1 - d.x0) / 2, 0.005))
            .padRadius(width / 4)
            .innerRadius(d => d.y0)
            .outerRadius(d => d.y1 - 1)
```

if i apply the values in the suggested method:

```
                    const ringInnerRadius = i.y0;
                    const ringOuterRadius = i.y1 -1;

                    const ringMidRadius = (ringInnerRadius + ringOuterRadius) / 2;

                    const sectorStartAngle = i.x0;
                    const sectorEndAngle = i.x1;
                    const sectorMidAngle = (sectorStartAngle + sectorEndAngle) / 2;

                    const scale = 1.5;

                    const transX = (1-scale) * ringMidRadius * Math.cos(sectorMidAngle);
                    const transY = (1-scale) * ringMidRadius * Math.sin(sectorMidAngle);
```

I come up with the following issue. Here you see the first level from the center, which is shifted and turned right away from the center:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you know the distance and angle of the center of the sector, then you can scale the sector by 1.5 and then translate it back to where it belongs.

```js
const ringInnerRadius = ...;
const ringOuterRadius = ...;
const ringMidRadius = (ringInnerRadius + ringOuterRadius) / 2;

const sectorStartAngle = ...;
const sectorEndAngle = ...;
const sectorMidAngle = (sectorStartAngle + sectorEndAngle) / 2;

const scale = 1.5;

const transX = (1-scale) * ringMidRadius * Math.cos(sectorMidAngle);
const transY = (1-scale) * ringMidRadius * Math.sin(sectorMidAngle);

sector.attr("transform", `translate(${transX} ${transY}) scale(1.5)`)
```

Comment: thanks for your help, applied your method and edited the result. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the coordinates of the center of your chart? I was assuming 0,0 but if not then you should translate it to the origin first, apply the transform, and then translate it back

Comment: you are correct, my origin is set as .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + width / 2 + ")"). But well i tried to set the attribute twice first with origin and than do the translate again, here another error shows up with cannot comput dommatrix whatsoever. Any idea how to tell d3 to do one thing after another?

Comment: even with the svg at 0,0 the transition wont work with your code. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is not resolved, and I do not get it working. Now, I use a different technique named sunburst with distortion to highlight different parts. I updated the code from https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1306365 (from the all famous Mike Bostock) for d3 v4 and posted the converted code as an answer to my question here: [d3js Sunburst with Distortion > v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72361353/d3js-sunburst-with-distortion-v4)